# Is there a way to give a subquery an alias in Oracle 11g SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle11g, table-alias

Is there a way to give a subquery in Oracle 11g an alias like:

```
select * 
from
    (select client_ref_id, request from some_table where message_type = 1) abc,
    (select client_ref_id, response  from some_table where message_type = 2) defg
where
    abc.client_ref_id = def.client_ref_id;
```

Otherwise is there a way to join the two subqueries based on the client_ref_id.  I realize there is a self join, but on the database I am running on a self join can take up to 5 min to complete (there is some extra logic in the actual query I am running but I have determined the self join is what is causing the issue).  The individual subqueries only take a few seconds to complete by them selves.  The self join query looks something like:

```
select st.request, st1.request
from
    some_table st, some_table st1
where 
    st.client_ref_id = st1.client_ref_id;
```

Comment: Just curious, how well did the accepted answer perform?

Comment: You haven't figured out it's the self-join. Make an identical copy of the table, indexes and statistics and see if you get the same timing. The better question would have been, "Help me tune this query" and posted the FULL query, and the explain plan.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can give a query a name or alias with CTE’s (Common Table Expressions) aka WITH clause aka by Oracle as Subquery Factoring:

```
WITH abc as (select client_ref_id, request from some_table where message_type = 1)
select * 
from abc
    inner join 
    (select client_ref_id, response  from some_table where message_type = 2) defg
       on abc.client_ref_id = def.client_ref_id;
```

Comment: What is the technical term for the "WITH abc as (select...)" part? If one wanted to research on its capabilities.

Comment: @SeaBass: Common Table Expressions, frequently abbreviated to CTE (also frequently used as the name/alias, although I dodn't do so this time). Note that both "tables" could have been done as part of the CTE, I just wanted to show both options, so did one one way and the other, the other.

Comment: @SeaBass Oracle has another term for CTEs: you can find specific Oracle resources for this with “Subquery Factoring” (or Recursive Subquery Factoring)

Answer (score 8):

I don't have an Oracle instance to test with, but what you posted should be valid ANSI-89 JOIN syntax.  Here it is in ANSI-92:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT client_ref_id, request 
          FROM SOME_TABLE 
         WHERE message_type = 1) abc
  JOIN (SELECT client_ref_id, request 
          FROM SOME_TABLE 
         WHERE message_type = 1) defg ON defg.client_ref_id = abc.client_ref_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query should be fine.

An alternative would be:

```
select abc.client_ref_id, abc.request, def.response
from   some_table abc,
       some_table def
where  abc.client_ref_id = def.client_ref_id
and    abc.message_type = 1
and    def.message_type = 2;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if Oracle rewrote the queries so that the plan would be the same anyway.

Comment: This solution is what is taking so long to complete on the database I am using. The statement 'abc.client_ref_id = def.client_ref_id' causes the query to go from a few seconds to take over an hour to complete.

Comment: You have to be very careful about timing. Are you talking about last row timing? or just first rows? Certain query plans can produce 1 row very fast (a second) but would take a year to produce the last row. Whereas others would get the last row in a minute.

Comment: @Matt, post the query plan - it's no good mucking around with the SQL when we don't know what's causing the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL standard you can define alias for subquery in this way

**SELECT** Temp.patente, Temp.SalarioProm 
**FROM** **( SELECT** A.aid aid, A.patente AS patente,
**AVG** (E.esalario) **AS** SalarioProm
**FROM** Aircraft A, Certified C, Employees E
**WHERE** A.aid = C.aid 
**AND** C.eid = E.eid 
**AND** A.rangocrucero > 1000
**GROUP BY** A.aid, A.patente **) AS** Temp

Where Temp is the alias for the subquery

In Oracle, you can use the clause WITH, especially when the subquery is complex and use a lot of temporary space.

In Oracle, the following syntax works fine

**SELECT** Temp.patente, Temp.SalarioProm 
**FROM** **( SELECT** A.aid aid, A.patente AS patente,
**AVG** (E.esalario) **AS** SalarioProm
**FROM** Aircraft A, Certified C, Employees E
**WHERE** A.aid = C.aid 
**AND** C.eid = E.eid 
**AND** A.rangocrucero > 1000
**GROUP BY** A.aid, A.patente **)** Temp

Comment: Please format code as code, as the other answers are. You can use the [editing help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to assist you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).